# Can Azure ASP.NET Web Forms be used to build an IoT application?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am an ASP.NET web forms programmer. While researching on IoT app development in Azure, I came across examples that use **ASP.NET MVC** or **ASP.NET core** for development.

I am keen to know whether **Azure ASP.NET Web Forms** app can be used for visualizing the IoT data.

Please confirm whether following data flow is valid?

IoT Device
    |
    ----> Azure IoT hub 
                     |
                      ----> Azure Stream Analytics Job
                                       |
                                      ----> Azure SQL Database 
                                                        |
                                                        ----> Azure ASP.NET Web forms application

Comment: Your question asks about consuming data from Azure IoT Hub while your flow shows consuming data from SQL Database.

Comment: Unfortunately this question, as written, is very broad, and there's really no objective way to answer this question. How you build your web app is really up to you. This will be dependent on what your data looks like, how you aggregated it into SQL DB from Stream Analytics, visualization tools you're using, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to improve the question further with more details, here.

In the Microsoft technet forum, I got a reply to this question that it is possible to visualize the IoT data using Azure ASP.NET Web Forms app too.

Following is the hyperlink to the reply, in the Microsoft technet forum -

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0602b73f-caef-4513-bb2c-3ed28badb2d0/can-azure-aspnet-web-forms-be-used-to-build-an-iot-application?forum=ssdsgetstarted